# Usage statistics collection for offline web apps

Tags: vue.js, user-experience, usage-statistics

we'd like to collect usage statistics on our Vue.js apps. The issue is that our applications are very frequently offline since they run close to industrial production lines. Can you suggest any product for the purpose? Basically we're looking for sort of Google Analytics but with it's own backend to be deployed locally.

Thanks for helping

Comment: A clearer term would be intranet/local and not offline. Any way, asking for libs is offtopic on SO. You'll likely get everything that could be suggested with "google analytics self-hosted" search

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks. I found better terminology and the right search string for my need. SO helped as always.